# C# windows Application with SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am Receiving this error:

> "The 'Employee_ID' property on 'Employee' could not be set to a
>   'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type
>   'String'."

The Employee_ID is type int but in debugging mode i see that the error in this line

```
List<Employee> employee = tse.Employee.ToList();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Seems easy enough. It's a cast error. Recast to proper type and you should be fine(in this case to a non null string)

Comment: Please post the code that causes the exception, the`Employee` class definition and the underlying column's type. The message is very clear - you've a string property with a numeric field. Either convert ID to an int, or the field to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change your property to nullable Int32 like this and try

```
public Int32? Employee_ID{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Inside the Employee class there should be a property Employee_ID. In List<Employee> keep the cursor on Employee and right click go to definition it will take you to employee class. There you need to check this property.

Answer (score 1):

Your Employee_ID is receiving a null value(because the id does not exist in the database) and int32 is a value type.
To stop this you can declare your id as a nullable int like this:

```
public int? Employee_ID{ get; set; }
```

but you will still have a null value in the Emplyoee_ID. I suggest that you check the database because you should not have a empty id

Comment: I know but in the app itself i need to add a new employee but i need the id to be auto incremented as i don't get the id from the user what should i do?

Comment: If the id is the primary key to the database you should have an option to auto increment.. just check that, and when you create a user you do not pass the id(in the app) the database will assign a value to the id. How are you adding the user? are you using the linq to sql framework?

Comment: this is how i am adding the user ===============================> private void btn_adduser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TSEntities tse = new TSEntities();
            tse.Employee.AddObject(
                new Employee
                {
                    Employee_User =txt_usernam.Text,
                    Employee_PassWord=txt_password.Text,
                    Employee_FullName=txt_Fullname.Text
                }
                );
            tse.SaveChanges();
            this.Close();
            }

Comment: In the Employee table in the database go to the Employee_ID and make it to autoincrement. (is the Employee_ID the primary key?)

Comment: done what you told me but now i am getting another error but to get it i have to let you know i have a screen in my app which loads in a grid view the employees data so in this function i am getting error here's the function code=>private void LoadData()
        {
            TSEntities tse = new TSEntities();
            List<Employee> employee = tse.Employee.ToList();
            if (txt_search.Text != "")
            {
                employee = employee.Where(e => e.Employee_User.Contains(txt_search.Text)).ToList();
            }
            gv_user.DataSource = employee;
        }

Comment: i am getting invalid operation exception error =>The 'Employee_ID' property on 'Employee' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'.

Comment: Then just declare the Employee_ID as nullable: public int? Employee_ID{ get; set; }

Comment: sorry for giving you hard time but where i should add this line of code ??

Comment: In the Employee class. If you can not find it just right click Employee and go to definition.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, your `Employee_ID` must be of type `string`.

```
public string Employee_ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: if i did so the id will not auto increment and i need it to be auto incremented am i right?

Comment: In that case you should change the database table to `int` and enable auto increment. Once you've done that and you've removed any string values, you can change the property back to `int`.

Comment: change database table to int then change the property back to int ??

Comment: Yes, change the database column `Employee_ID` to `int`, and then leave the C# property `public int Employee_ID { get; set; }`.

Comment: where should i write this (public int Employee_ID { get; set; }) please advise